# Fixing "The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data" in SAS. Converting Access SQL to Proc SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sas, proc-sql

Beginner here. I am attempting to convert some inherited Access queries into SAS but am running into an issue of returning more records in SAS with many duplicates vs running in Access that appear to be an issue of grouping and summing certain variables. In SAS I am met with the warning: "The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data" in SAS.

Would like to know what is a better way to rewrite the Access SQL code as I am more or less just copying and changing it to work via Proc SQL in SAS. Believe the issue occurs at the creation of variables starting with the name "SumofSum" in ComboQuery, and a difference to how they are treated in Access vs SAS.

**ACCESS SQL**

**Rev_Query**

```
SELECT
       [Rev].Contract,
       [Rev].[Posting Date],
       [Rev].[Documnet Number],
       Sum([Rev].Amount) AS SumOfAmount,
       Sum([Rev].[Reclass Amt]) AS [SumOfReclass Amt]
FROM   [Rev]
GROUP  BY 
       [Rev].Contract,     
       [Rev].[Posting Date],   
       [Rev].[Documnet Number];
```

**Remit_Query**

```
SELECT 
       [Remit].[ID],
       Sum([Remit].[CCHS Amt]) AS [SumOfCCHS Amt]
FROM   [Remit Data]
GROUP  BY 
       [Remit Data].[ID];
```

**ComboQuery**

```
SELECT 
       [Rev_Query].Contract,
       Sum([Rev_Query].SumOfAmount) AS SumOfSumOfAmount,
       Sum([Rev_Query].[SumOfReclass Amt]) AS [SumOfSumOfReclass Amt],
       Sum([Remit_Query].[SumOfCCHS Amt]) AS [SumOfSumOfCCHS Amt],
       Sum(Round(Nz([Rev_Query] ! [SumOfReclass Amt]) + Nz([Remit_Query] ! [SumOfCCHS Amt]), 2)) AS Expr1
FROM   [Remit_Query]
RIGHT JOIN 
       [Rev_Query]
ON 
       [Remit_Query].[ID] = [Rev_Query].[Documnet Number]
GROUP  BY 
       [Rev_Query].Contract
HAVING 
       (((Sum(Round(Nz([Rev_Query] ! [SumOfReclass Amt]) + Nz([Remit_Query] ! [SumOfCCHS Amt), 2)) ) <> 0 ));
```

**SAS**

**Rev_Query**

```
proc sql;
create table hw.Rev_Query as
select 
   t1.Contract,
   t1.Posting_Date,
   t1.Document_Number,
   sum(t1.Amount) as SumOfAmount,
   sum(t1.Reclass_Amt) as SumOfReclassAmt
from hw.Revenue as t1
group by 1,2,3;
quit;
```

**Remit_Query**

```
proc sql;
create table hw.Remit_Query as
select 
   t1.ID,
   sum(t1.CCHS_Amt) as SumOfCCHS_Amt
from hw.Remit as t1
group by 1;
quit;
```

**ComboQuery**

```
proc sql;
create table hw.ComboQuery as
select 
   t1.Contract,
   sum(t1.SumOfAmount) as SumOfSumOfAmount,
   sum(t1.SumOfReclassAmt) as SumOfSumOfReclassAmt,
   sum(t2.SumOfCCHS_Amt) as SumOfSumOfCCHS_Amt,
   sum(t1.SumOfReclassAmt,t2.SumOfCCHS_Amt) as Expr1
from hw.Remit_Query t2
right join hw.Rev_Query t1 on t2.ID = t1.Document_Number
group by 1
having Expr1 <> 0;
quit;
```

Comment: I doubt the query would work in Access if it requires re-merging to work in SAS.  Most SQL implementations do not support including extra variables that are neither a grouping variable nor a summary statistic, which is what is required for SAS to issue that message.

Comment: Which of the three queries you posted is triggering that message?  Are the inputs datasets? or views?  If the input is a view then perhaps it that view's definition that is generating the message and not the code you have shown.

Comment: Of the three queries, I think I see what's triggering the message in ComboQuery. The line "having Expr1 <> 0;". Earlier in the code, Expr1 is sum(t1.SumofReclassAmt,t2.SumofSumofCCHS). Also, the inputs from the library 'hw' are datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function SUM(a,b) you used in the last query is NOT the SQL function SUM() that aggregates across observations.  That is why you are getting the remerging.

I have no idea what the heck the gibberish you have in the ACCESS query means:

```
Sum(
  Round(Nz([Rev_Query] ! [SumOfReclass Amt])
      + Nz([Remit_Query] ! [SumOfNet Amt To CCHS])
      , 2
       )
)
```

But is does not look like it is just trying to add two numbers together which is what SUM(a,b) means.

SAS does not have an NZ() function.  Figure out what that does in ACCESS and map that to something.  Perhaps you can replicate it with a CASE clause. Or perhaps it just a COALESCE() function.  Perhaps you could use the goofy IFN() function SAS added recently.

Also SAS has a ROUND() function, but I doubt that you would want to round to even integers which is what ROUND(X,2) would do in SAS.  Most likely in ACCESS that means round to 2 decimal places which in SAS would be ROUND(x,0.01).

Perhaps:

```
  sum(round(sum(0,t1.SumOfReclassAmt,t2.SumOfSumOfCCHS),.01)) as Expr1
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work and get rid of the message "The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data."

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(sum(t1.SumOfReclassAmt) + sum(t2.SumOfSumOfCCHS)) as Expr1
```

If you want missings to be zeroes, which you might need if a column is all nulls, try

```
(
  sum(coalesce(t1.SumOfReclassAmt,0)) 
+ sum(coalesce(t2.SumOfSumOfCCHS,0))
) as Expr1
```

Wouldn't hurt to also change `<>` to SAS `ne` (not equal) operator/mnemonic.

Comment: Similar to Tom's response, this also worked and got rid of the message "The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data". Thank you both!